# SSH ForwardAgent + multi-Host

Tags: ssh, github, ssh-agent

I have several Hosts in ~/.ssh/config, and they work fine from local machine, but remote machine doesn't know these Hosts.

```
Host A
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/A_rsa
Host B
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/B_rsa
Host remotemachine.com
    ForwardAgent yes
```

From localhost:

```
$ ssh -T git@A
Hi A! You've successfully authenticated, ...
$ ssh -T git@B
Hi B! You've successfully authenticated, ...
```

From remote host:

```
$ ssh remotemachine
$ ssh-add -l
  ... both keys present ...
$ ssh -T git@B
ssh: Could not resolve hostname B: Name or service not known
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi A! You've successfully authenticated, ...
```

How to use key B on remote machine?

That said, from local machine I'm able to do `ssh git@B`, but on remote machine hostname `B` is not known. Seems like ssh-agent forwards only keys, but not hosts. How to make it forward hosts too?

I could create ~/.ssh/config on remote machine too, but what to put into IdentityFile?
I could use `$ ssh -i KEYFILE`, but what to put into KEYFILE if keys are forwarded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the only way to do this is to use `ssh -i` or to create `~/.ssh/config` on every machine, with the same `IdentityFile` settings.

However, it is enough to copy the **public** keys to other servers. That is, *not* `~/.ssh/A_rsa`, but only `~/.ssh/A_rsa.pub`. The ssh client will use the agent for private keys, just like it already does on your local machine.